# multicolumn doesn't count columns property in pgfplotstable

Tags: longtable, pgfplotstable, multicolumn

Consider the following MWE where I would expect the `multicolumn` to span the number of columns in the `pgfplotstable`/`longtable` combination.

```
\multicolumn{\pgfplotstablecols}{r}{{\small\tablename\ \thetable{} -- will continue.}}
```

The number of columns should be four, according to the supplied `.csv` file, but somehow `multicolumn` doesn't span properly unless i type

```
\multicolumn{6}{r}{{\small\tablename\ \thetable{} -- will continue.}}
```

This is the output, which obviously isn't aligned to the right spanning all columns. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs,longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
/pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,}
\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
}
\sisetup{exponent-product = {\cdot},output-decimal-marker={,}, per-mode=symbol}

\begin{filecontents}{table.csv}
Period;     M1;     M2;     M3
a;        9,4;    1706;   1706
b;        9,2;    1135;   2841
c;        9,4;    1319;   4160
d;        9,4;    1525;   5685
e;        9,2;    1367;   7052
f;        9,5;    1261;   8313
g;        9,3;    1814;   10127
h;        9,2;    1450;   1157
a;        9,4;    1706;   1706
b;        9,2;    1135;   2841
c;        9,4;    1319;   4160
d;        9,4;    1525;   5685
e;        9,2;    1367;   7052
f;        9,5;    1261;   8313
g;        9,3;    1814;   10127
h;        9,2;    1450;   1157
a;        9,4;    1706;   1706
b;        9,2;    1135;   2841
c;        9,4;    1319;   4160
d;        9,4;    1525;   5685
e;        9,2;    1367;   7052
f;        9,5;    1261;   8313
g;        9,3;    1814;   10127
h;        9,2;    1450;   1157
a;        9,4;    1706;   1706
b;        9,2;    1135;   2841
c;        9,4;    1319;   4160
d;        9,4;    1525;   5685
e;        9,2;    1367;   7052
f;        9,5;    1261;   8313
g;        9,3;    1814;   10127
h;        9,2;    1450;   11577
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

{\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    col sep=semicolon,
    read comma as period=true,
    header=true,
    every head row/.style={
        before row={%
            \caption{Some caption}%
            \label{tab:sometable}\tabularnewline\toprule%
        }, % before row
        after row={\midrule\endhead\midrule\multicolumn{\pgfplotstablecols}{r}{{\small\tablename\ \thetable{} -- will continue.}}\endfoot
        \bottomrule\endlastfoot%
        }, % after row
    }, % every head row
    display columns/0/.style={column type={l},string type},
    display columns/1/.style={string type, column type={S[table-format=2.2, add-decimal-zero=true]}},
    display columns/2/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
    display columns/3/.style={sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,},
]{table.csv}\par
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a line like

```
        after row={
a&b&c&d&e&f\\
\midrule\endhead\midrule\multicolumn{\pgfplotstablecols}{r}{{\small\tablename\ \thetable{} -- will continue.}}\endfoot
        \bottomrule\endlastfoot%
        }, % after row
```

then you see

[image]

Showing that the decimal alignment is using two columns internally which you need to take account of. (Or you could perhaps use `dcolumn` decimal alignment which uses a single column)

Comment: Aha! Where should I have spotted this before? :-) Moving the `before` and `after row` after the `display columns` statements did the trick!